# Remove li with attribute jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove a list item li that has a specific attribute.

My current attempts fail.

```
id = $(this).attr('data-id');        
$.post('uri.../delete_file/' + id).done(function(data) 
{           
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  if (obj.status == 'success') 
  {
    $('li["data-id=' + id +'"]').remove();
  }
}
```

FireBug is informing that the jQuery expression is wrong.

```
$('li["data-id=' + id +'"]').remove();
```

The list item must have an attribute of `data-id=""`

**UPDATE - PHP and HTML**

```
<?php foreach($files as $file): ?>

<li data-id="<?php echo $file->id;?>">

    <a href='#' class='delete_file' data-id="<?php echo $file->id;?>">[X] Delete</a>

</li>   

<?php endforeach;?>
```

**UPDATE 2 - Message from FireBug**

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ["data-id=1"]


throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
```

Comment: can you share the html

Comment: Are you sure that li is defined? and that it does not contain special characters that would break the selector?

Comment: Try removing the double-quotes from your expression.

Comment: firebug will never tell you "something is wrong". It will tell you what *went* wrong, so please tell us what you're seeing it say, what you expected, and ideally, the example as a jsfiddle.net bit of runnable code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you wrong on putting double quote. it's must:

```
$('li[data-id="' + id +'"]').remove();
```